# Meaning of predict.fixed and predict.Subject in predict function of nlme

Tags: r, nlme

I am trying to understand what the predicted values represent in the predict function in nlme

I am using the data and code given in the nlme manual for the `predict` function as an example

```
library(nlme)
fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, Orthodont, random = ~ age | Subject)
    newOrth <- data.frame(Sex = c("Female","Female","Female","Female","Male","Male"),
                          age = c(15, 20, 10, 12, 2, 4),
                          Subject = c("M01","M01","F30","F30","M04","M04"))
    ## The  Orthodont  data has *no*  F30 , so predict  NA  at level 1 :
    predict(fm1, newOrth, level = 0:1)
```

What is the difference between the `predict.fixed` and `predict.Subject` column?

I gather that if we leave out the `levels` argument we get the predicted value, at each requested value of `age`, for each subject, and that this is the `0` in the `0:1` of the `levels` argument. But what is `predict.fixed` and how is it useful?

Comment: By default you get *conditional* predictions, specific to each Subject.  The level-0 predictions, as explained in the documentation, are the population or *marginal* predictions.  These are the predictions for the "average"  subject in the population sampled.  If we want to make population-level inference, rather than to these specific subjects, we use the level-0 predictions.

Comment: The discussion of conditional vs marginal predictions may be better suited for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). See, for example, [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86309/marginal-model-versus-random-effects-model-how-to-choose-between-them-an-advi)

Comment: Thank you @aosmith, yes I guess it is veering into CV territory. I am still confused though. Firstly the answer in link you provided states that the estimates of marginal and conditional models coincide, yet the estimates in the two columns - `predict.fixed` and `predict.ID` - for each individual are different. Secondly if the estimates are for the average subject, why are they all different? i.e. in what sense are they average?

Comment: Your questions now really sound like statistics questions.  If you don't want to move the question, [keep reading](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59137/subject-specific-vs-population-average-predictions/68531#68531) on population-level and subject-level predictions and it should become clear how one type is the effect for the "average" subject (so random effects are 0) and one type adds in the "subject" effect.

Comment: thank you once again @aosmith I am starting to get a sense of it. I will ask the question on CV as I am still not clear on how 'holding the random effects constant' (in the case of subject-specific) differs from 'averaging across random effects' (in the case of the population-level estimates)